# Is it bad to have a computer running at maximum temperature for a long period of time?

Tags: laptop, cpu, macbook, battery, temperature

I'm having a Macbook pro 15" 2012 model here and I remember the past when I gamed on my Macbook- specifically World of Warcraft. When I played this game my Macbook went from a passive ~55 degrees C to the maximum of 105 degrees C. This also (of course) drains the battery which usually last 4 hours to a mere 30-40 minutes (with a full charge). Of course, I did gave the machine room to 'breathe'.

This was one of the reasons I stopped playing games in general on my Macbook.

But I'm quite curious whether having a machine running on it's maximum temperature is bad for the machine itself- and having the battery drain as crazy is bad for the battery itself.

One might say "*yes*", but I could think of an answer such as "*If it doesn't shuts itself down (precaution) it isn't bad*". What is true?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/431309/what-is-the-impact-of-running-the-cpu-at-100-for-long-periods-at-a-time and http://superuser.com/questions/294238/is-it-okay-to-have-100-cpu-usage-constantly and http://superuser.com/questions/749146/safe-long-term-cpu-temp

Comment: @slhck Question: Is this good practice to mark it as duplicate and link it to a *closed* question? That closed question cannot be improved anymore

Comment: @nixda Well, it doesn't *have* to be improved. It just also highlights that there could be an issue with the scope of the question altogether, in the sense of it being too broad or not objectively answerable except for "it might be bad".